# OpenCV 2 Centroid

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, centroid

I am trying to find the centroid of a contour but am having trouble implementing the example code in C++ (OpenCV 2.3.1). Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To find the centroid of a contour, you can use the method of moments. And functions are implemented OpenCV.

Check out these moments function ([central and spatial moments](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html)).

Below code is taken from OpenCV 2.3 docs tutorial. [Full code here.](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/moments/moments.html?highlight=moment#code)

---

```
/// Find contours
findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

/// Get the moments
vector<Moments> mu(contours.size() );
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
 { mu[i] = moments( contours[i], false ); }

///  Get the mass centers:
vector<Point2f> mc( contours.size() );
for( int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++ )
 { mc[i] = Point2f( mu[i].m10/mu[i].m00 , mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00 ); }
```

---

Also [check out this SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056646/python-opencv-find-black-areas-in-a-binary-image), although it is in Python, it would be useful. It finds all parameters of a contour.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the mask of the contour area, you can find the centroid location as follows:

```
cv::Point computeCentroid(const cv::Mat &mask) {
    cv::Moments m = moments(mask, true);
    cv::Point center(m.m10/m.m00, m.m01/m.m00);
    return center;
}
```

This approach is useful when one has the mask but not the contour. In that case the above method is computationally more efficient vs. using `cv::findContours(...)` and then finding mass center.

[Here's the source](http://answers.opencv.org/question/460/finding-centroid-of-a-mask/)

Comment: how do you get a mask of the contour area, given a Contour?

Answer (score 1):

Given the contour points, and the formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid#Centroid_of_polygon), the centroid can be efficiently computed like this:

```
template <typename T> 
cv::Point_<T> computeCentroid(const std::vector<cv::Point_<T> >& in) {
    if (in.size() > 2) {
         T doubleArea = 0;
         cv::Point_<T> p(0,0);
         cv::Point_<T> p0 = in->back();
         for (const cv::Point_<T>& p1 : in) {//C++11
             T a = p0.x * p1.y - p0.y * p1.x; //cross product, (signed) double area of triangle of vertices (origin,p0,p1)
             p += (p0 + p1) * a;
             doubleArea += a;
             p0 = p1;
         }

         if (doubleArea != 0)
             return p * (1 / (3 * doubleArea) ); //Operator / does not exist for cv::Point
    }

    ///If we get here,
    ///All points lies on one line, you can compute a fallback value,
    ///e.g. the average of the input vertices
    [...]
}
```

Note:

- This formula works with vertices given both in clockwise and
  counterclockwise order.
- If the points have integer coordinates, it
  might be convenient to adapt the type of `p` and of the return value to `Point2f` or `Point2d`,
  and to add a cast to `float` or `double` to the denominator in the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is an approximation of the centroid here are a couple of simple ways to do it:

```
sumX = 0; sumY = 0;
size = array_points.size;
if(size > 0){

    foreach(point in array_points){
        sumX += point.x;
        sumY += point.y;
    }
            
 centroid.x = sumX/size;
 centroid.y = sumY/size;
}
```

Or with the help of Opencv's boundingRect:

```
//pseudo-code:

Rect bRect = Imgproc.boundingRect(array_points);

centroid.x = bRect.x + (bRect.width / 2);
centroid.y = bRect.y + (bRect.height / 2);
```

Comment: This doesn't find the [centroid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centroid) of a contour. The first, for example, is just an average of the corner points.

Comment: Yes I should have mentioned it is an aproximation. Useful if you only need a rough result.