# Finding separate centroids of each white spots in a frame?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm doing finger detection i.e. the fingertips using VGA camera. I have used HSV and image thresholding and I am able to detect the fingertips.

The Problem: I can now find the centroid of the white spot in a black and white image if there is only one white spot (if I place just one finger); but if I place multiple fingers more white spots will come in the final image. So I want to find each centroid separately.

I want to find all centroids of each of the white spots i.e. if I place more than one finger in front of the camera. Look at the code below

```
thresholded_img =  cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(hsv_img), 8, 1) 
cv.InRangeS(hsv_img, (0,0,200), (0,0,255), thresholded_img)
moments = cv.Moments(cv.GetMat(thresholded_img,1), 0) 
area = cv.GetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0) 
x = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0)/area 
y = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1)/area 
posY=y
posX=x
```

Here `thresholded_img` is a black and white image where the fingertips alone is represented as white and all other in black.

In this code if the `thresholded_img` contains a single white spot then I can get the `x` and `y` coordinates of the centroid of that dot correctly!

But how to find centroid of each white dots in this image?

[image: dd]

But if there is multiple white dots in the thresholded image then it's finding wrong centroid!

How can I change the above code to find (x,y coordinates) separate centroid of each white dots in a single frame (image)?

Refer this image please.
http://www.csksoft.net/data/pic/laserkbd/036.jpg

Comment: btw, please use the cv2 api instead, the outdated cv one won't be there in the next version.

Comment: if you'd use findContours, you could get the moments/centroids for each single contour found.

Comment: can someone give me a sample code that finds seperate centriods of the white dots in the image above??

Comment: @user3429616 See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23845071/15485

Answer (score 2):

I tested the following code with [the image you uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFOUG.jpg).

I got the following textual output:

```
cv2 version: 2.4.4
centroids: [(580, 547), (437, 546), (276, 545), (115, 545), (495, 425), (334, 424), (174, 424), (24, 423), (581, 304), (437, 303), (277, 303), (117, 302), (495, 182), (334, 181), (174, 181), (25, 181), (581, 60), (438, 59), (277, 59), (117, 59)]
```

and this image:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import cv2

img = cv2.imread('HFOUG.jpg',cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
_,img = cv2.threshold(img,0,255,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
h, w = img.shape[:2]

contours0, hierarchy = cv2.findContours( img.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
moments  = [cv2.moments(cnt) for cnt in contours0]
# Nota Bene: I rounded the centroids to integer.
centroids = [( int(round(m['m10']/m['m00'])),int(round(m['m01']/m['m00'])) ) for m in moments]

print 'cv2 version:', cv2.__version__
print 'centroids:', centroids

for c in centroids:
    # I draw a black little empty circle in the centroid position
    cv2.circle(img,c,5,(0,0,0))

cv2.imshow('image', img)
0xFF & cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

See also this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/9059648/15485 to the question [Python OpenCV - Find black areas in a binary image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056646/python-opencv-find-black-areas-in-a-binary-image/)

Comment: Here it gives a float division by zero when it finds a spot... Note that my spot isn't 100% filled, maybe that's why.

Comment: @Fusseldieb I have tested the code only on the image of the question. According to `cv::Moments Class Reference` in 
Image Processing » Structural Analysis and Shape Descriptors https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d8/d23/classcv_1_1Moments.html *Since the contour moments are computed using Green formula, you may get seemingly odd results for contours with self-intersections, e.g. a zero area (`m00`) for butterfly-shaped contours.*